# Regex - Optional Group With Replacement

Tags: .net, regex-group, regexp-replace

I need to capture up to four digits, as follows, in a named group:

```
    123       -> 123
    2357      -> 2357
    123 (11X) -> 11
    235 (7Y)  -> 7
```

As you can see, the bracketed number and letter is optional.
Though there appear to be similar questions on the forum, my limited knowledge prevents me from adapting their solutions.

My initial attempt is, as follows:

```
(?<ABC>\d{0,4})?|\((?<DEF>\d{0,4})(?<GHI>[A-Za-z])\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nJOZYAHFrGivERjp)
seems to capture the groups I need, but how do I automatically choose the correct group in a replacement context - ABC or DEF depending on the input?

Do I need a 'branch reset' so that I can give groups 'ABC' and 'DEF' the same name and, if so, how do I implement it?

Please advise?

Comment: ```\d+``` will catch any occurrence of a string of digits; if you need further help please show us what you have attempted thus far and I will be more than happy to assist you

Comment: ```\d{1,4}``` if you only want to capture at most 4 digit numbers

Comment: @CyberStems, Thanks for the reply. See edited question for my initial attempt at a soluton.

Comment: which language are you using? Or are you just wanting to do this through a command line?

Comment: @CyberStems. I am using F# - so similar to C#-

Comment: @matekus While regex exists in many languages, each language supports a different "dialect", so it's usually a good idea to tag the language.  For example, recursive/balanced subgroup matching is still unsupported in modern JavaScript implementations.

Comment: @Amy. Is the '.NET' tag not sufficient?

Comment: @matekus Probably.  It's up to you.

Comment: `{0,4}` meaning zero to four items?

Comment: @ ΩmegaMan. What I intended was to represent numbers of up to four digits - for example - 1, 12, 123, or 1234.

Comment: @Martin Ender. Would you mind reviewing this question.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, the following pattern works for .NET [ [Solution](https://regex101.com/r/VySgwU/6) ]:

```
    (?<ABC>\d{0,4}) ?\((?<ABC>\d{0,4})(?<GHI>[A-Za-z])?\)
```